# Getting error while running the sample code of COCOS2DX 'HelloCpp'

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Getting error while running the sample code of COCOS2DX 'HelloCpp'. Below are the error shown while running the project.

**Console Output:**

```
[2014-08-21 21:48:15 - HelloCpp]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2014-08-21 21:48:15 - HelloCpp]       Unable to add 'D:\Cocos2d-X\cocos2d-x-2.2.5\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\assets\app.icf': Zip add failed
[2014-08-21 21:48:15 - HelloCpp] ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging 'D:\Cocos2d-X\cocos2d-x-2.2.5\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_'
[2014-08-21 21:48:15 - HelloCpp] ERROR: packaging of 'D:\Cocos2d-X\cocos2d-x-2.2.5\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_' failed
```

**Error Logs:**

```
1. Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Cocos2d-X\cocos2d-x-2.2.5\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist
2. Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.
```

**Warning:**

```
Invalid project path: Include path not found (D:\Updated Eclipse\android-ndk-r10\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3\prebuilt\darwin-x86\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.4.3\include).
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: don't use paths with spaces or special characters in them for development tools, ie a path like "D:\Updated Eclipse\" can still potentially cause problems even in this day and age.

Comment: Now I have changed the Path for NDK, set it to C:\android-ndk-r10 but the problem is still not fixed.                                                           /LabelReader.cpp:54:9: error: 'transform' is not a member of 'std'
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r10/build/core/build-binary.mk:449: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos_extension_static/CocoStudio/Reader/WidgetReader/LabelReader/LabelReader.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos_extension_static/CocoStudio/Reader/WidgetReader/LabelReader/LabelReader.o] Error 1